# Proof that Markov shift is pointwise dual ergodic

Tags: reference-request, ergodic-theory

I am looking for a reference of the proof that a Markov shift is pointwise dual ergodic, I tried google it but with no success.

Comment: Yes, the transition matrix is irreducible and recurrent.

Comment: For this case, we have use some argument of the spectrum analysis of primitive matrix, I think the good book for beginner is Peter Walters' an introduction to ergodic theory.

Comment: On which pages does he discuss this topic?

Comment: I was looking at Walters' book, he doesn't discuss over there the topic of pointwise dual ergodicity.

Comment: Sorry, an introduction to infinite ergodic theory page 126.

Comment: Right, the book by Aaronson, I looked over it but I haven't found it. thanks!